# Aggregate fact table creation issue

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck in one place creating agg table.

My fact table has following fields - Location Key, Dekade Key and Data 
My Location dim table is as follows - Location Key, Code, Sub region

I create an aggregate fact table for average of data grouped by dekade key and location key, so my aggregated fact table looks like this - 
This is a sum group by of data with Dekade key and Location Key.

```
Location Key----Dekade Key----Data (sum aggr) 
2----------2688-------200 
3----------2688-------300 
4----------2688-------400
```

But here's the issue, I need to average the above data by 3 since number of location key for that subregion is only 3 in fact table. It should be (200+300+400)/3. My location dim has four keys -

```
Location Key----Code----Subregion 
1----------1234------Wisconsin 
2----------5876-------Wisconsin 
3----------3398-------Wisconsin 
4----------2978-------Wisconsin
```

Since the location key = 1 with code = 1234, has not reported any data, it wont appear in fact table. Say if it appears (has reported data) then we have to average the data in fact table by 4 to create the aggregate table. 
How to do this? Do i need any modification to be made in FACT or DIM tables?

If i do an outer join of fact table with the dim table the result will be like this -

```
Location Key----Code----Subregion---Location_Key_Dim
Null----------Null------Null-----------1 
2----------5876-------Wisconsin--------2 
3----------3398-------Wisconsin--------3 
4----------2978-------Wisconsin--------4
```

Location_Key_Dim is the key one from Dim table after doing outer join.

The expected result should be
Subregion----Aggregate 
Wisconsin-----(200+300+400)/3

Comment: Your design doesn't make any sense.  If your number of dimensions can change, then you can't really store averages.  Calculate it on the fly.

Comment: Dimension in dimension table is not changing. Dimension tables are delta loaded with INSERT so no deletions. Only the corresponding value in the fact table changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `OUTER JOIN` of the fact table with the dimension table to include dimensions with no facts. The aggregate results will depend on the aggregation you use.

Comment: If i do an outer join with the dimension table then the result will have all the missing dimension as well. In my case, the result will have all the location keys 1,2,3,4. Where as my requirement is to divide the sum of the fact by total number of keys in the fact table.

Comment: Then, I don't understand. Edit the question to include the query, actual results along with the expected results. Then, it may be possible to understand the requirement.

Comment: I think i should do an inner join